# How to pass string parameters in jenkins bat scripts

Tags: jenkins-scriptler

My `jenkins` projects has a parameterized build. I am trying to pass a String parameter to a bat script as `***.ps1 -param1=$param1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access environment variables (including job paramters) in your script by using `%param1%`. Environment variable should already be accessible withing your bat script environment (e.g. you don't have to pass them to the bat script if you are running it as a build step). However, if you are trying to pass a parameter on the command line, you should be able to access the parameter like this: `${param1}`.